# Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, quicksort

I wrote the Quicksort code in c++ but it is not working. can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? Whenever I am giving the input, it does not return any output.
example:

5

5 4 3 6 2

---

Process exited after 5.997 seconds with return value 3221225725
Press any key to continue . . .

why is it not returning any output? even though I checked the code many time but still I am facing the same problem

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b)           //swap function 

{

    int c;

    c=*b;

    *b=*a;

    *a=c;

}

int partition(int arr[], int i, int j)             //partition function

 {

    int pivot=arr[j];
    while(i<j) {
        while(i<=pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while(j>=pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if(i<j) {
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&pivot,&arr[j]);
    return j;
}

void quicksort(int arr[], int i, int j)   //quicksort function

 {

    if(i<j) {
        int p;
        p=partition(arr,i,j);
        quicksort(arr,i,p-1);
        quicksort(arr,p+1,j);
    }
}

    void print(int arr[],int n)      //function to print the array
    
     {
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    
    }

int main() 

{

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int x=0,y=n-1;
    quicksort(arr,x,y);
    print(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. What have you tried so far to attempt to troubleshoot this yourself? Have you stepped through the code with an actual debugger? "*it is not working*" is not a valid description of the problem. What exactly is not working? What input is being given? What is the expected output, and what is the actual output? Be specific.

Comment: Every time I insert an input, it does not give any output. It simply says- 
Process exited after 5.997 seconds with return value 3221225725
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: diable the quicksort function, first take the input and print it, see if its taking input correctly

Comment: I have already tried this and it is taking input correctly. @sittsering

Comment: What does your compiler have to say of `int arr[n];` once you enable warnings?

Comment: @Bob__ compiler is showing 0 warnings and 0 errors.

Comment: I think something is wrong in your `partition` function

Comment: @Princy decimal 3221225725 is hex 0xC00000FD, which is the error code for a `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW` exception. The most common cause of that error is unending recursion that pushes more and more data (function parameters, local variables, etc) on the call stack until it fills to capacity and fails.

Comment: `int arr[n]` is not standard `c++`. Also don't use `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `while(arr[i]<=pivot)` instead of `while(i<=pivot)` same goes for `j`

```
int partition(int arr[], int i, int j) 

 {

    int pivot=arr[j];
    while(i<j) {
        while(arr[i]<=pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while(arr[j]>pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if(i<j) {
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&pivot,&arr[j]);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sittsering. It helped. Also, I changed `while(arr[j]>=pivot)` to `while(arr[j]>pivot)` and it worked.